# Azure B2C - enable logins without needing to create a User

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to use Azure B2C to authenticate my web app.

I've set it up as multi-tenant - but when someone tries to log in from their work account (johnsmith@anothercompany.com) then the login shows this error:

AADSTS50020: User account 'johnsmith@anothercompany.com' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxx/' does not exist in tenant 'MyTenant' and cannot access the application 'yyy'(My Tool) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

... if I add johnsmith@anothercompany.com as a guest user in my B2C Tenant, then this works - John can log in.

Is there a way to enable my application to not require me to add "guest accounts", and just authenticate against any AAD tenant? (leaving authorization up to my app)

Comment: You configure multi-tenant based on this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy? If yes, note that you need to configure the multi tenant id here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-azure-ad-as-an-identity-provider.

Comment: `<Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,https://login.microsoftonline.com/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</Item>`. This allows you directly to sign in with the account of tenant `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` and `11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111`.

Comment: I agree with @AllenWu, you need to implement custom policies as per the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure multi-tenant based on this document: [Set up sign-in for multi-tenant Azure Active Directory using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)

You can set multiple AAD as identity providers by following [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-azure-ad-as-an-identity-provider).

`<Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,https://login.microsoftonline.com/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</Item>`

This allows you directly to sign in with the account of tenant `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` and `11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111`.